# Growth rate of bacteria involving logarithmic functions

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I was trying to solve the following question but I keep getting the wrong answer, could anyone help me out and see why?

A bacteria culture starts with 900 bacteria and grows at a rate proportional to its size. After 4 hours there will be 3600 bacteria. How long will it take for the population to reach 1150 ?

I found the equation to represent this problem as: $900*e^{.347t}$.

I then set this equation equal to 1150: $900*e^{.347t} = 1150$.  I end up with the expression: $ln(1.27778) = .347t$ which when I solve I get 0.7064, which is giving me the wrong answer in my homework. Did I miss a step I have to take?

Comment: you have the correct answer to the problem - probably there is a typo in your book's answers

Comment: I obtained $t = 0.7073$ since I did not round off $\ln(4)/4$ in my calculations.